# Where today date is inbetween from and todate

Tags: sql-server

I am using the below code to filter out the records where today’s date is between the from date and the to date.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[QUANTITY] where (getdate() >= fromdate and (todate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')) or (getdate() between fromdate and todate)
```

Because in some records from date and to date are 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

[image]

Need to verify if I am filtering it out properly.

Comment: that's not mysql syntax. mssql, perhaps? for mysql, you'd just do `WHERE curdate() BETWEEN fromdate AND todate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use between anywhere

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[QUANTITY]
WHERE   fromdate <= GETDATE()
        AND (todate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' OR todate >= GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell exactly what you are asking, but if you just want the ones where the dates are between `fromDate` and `toDate`, just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[QUANTITY] 
WHERE getdate() BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate
```

If you want a period starting with something different than "no value" (`1900-01-01`) and ending with "no value" (`1900-01-01`) (X to infinity), then do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[QUANTITY] 
WHERE getdate() BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate
OR (toDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' AND getdate() BETWEEN fromDate AND getdate())
```